# $variable = $_POST['variable'].$_GET['variable']; Is this acceptable?

Tags: php, post, get, pagination

Input form like

```
<form action="<?php echo (htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] .'?page=1')) ?>" method="post">

<input type='text' name='date_month' value='<?php echo $_POST['date_month'].$_GET['date_month']?>'>

</form>
```

Then receive the input

```
$post_date_month = $_POST['date_month'].$_GET['date_month'];
```

Based on the input select/get filtered data from mysql

As there may be many rows of data, created pagination. Like this

```
for ($page_i = 1; $page_i <= $total_pages; $page_i++) {
echo "<a href='__filter_mysql_data.php?page=$page_i&date_month=$post_date_month&date_year=$post_date_year'>| $page_i |</a> ";
}
```

**Note!** If in url I do not use `&date_month=$post_date_month` then when user clicks on page number `$page_i`, script will display all data from mysql (not based on `$post_date_month`; not only month selected by user, but all months because after page reload `$_POST['date_month']` "disappears").

Now this is the only working solution for me (have found several examples with pagination class, but these examples are very complicated for me so can not in reasonable time ammend for my needs). So decided to create something simple.

The script works as necessary, only this `$post_date_month = $_POST['date_month'].$_GET['date_month'];` looks a bit 'crazy'. So the question: is the code acceptable (can be used in scripts)? With the same query (click) user can set/pass either $_POST or $_GET and never the both.

Update

Based on Ø Hanky Panky Ø advice (that unfortunatelly is deleted) changed

`$post_date_month = $_POST['date_month'].$_GET['date_month'];`

to

`$post_date_month = $_REQUEST['date_month'];`

Comment: Please use `htmlspecialchars` to prevent XSS when outputting user data.

Comment: Read the docs for `$_REQUEST`.  http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Comment: @ Marcel Korpel `htmlspecialchars` is used in '<?php echo (htmlspecialchars'. I will check other places....

Comment: Not in `value='<?php echo $_POST['date_month'].$_GET['date_month']?>'`, not in `date_month=$post_date_month` (where you should `urlencode` the parameter) and don't put a space between the `@` and my name to call me properly.

Comment: @Crontab But when `$_GET['blah']` contains `foo`, `$_POST['blah']` contains `bar`, what will `$_REQUEST['blah']` contain? Is it `foo`, `bar`, `foobar` or `barfoo`?

Comment: is there a reason why you can not just use `method="get"` on your form also?

Comment: Just tried several experiments with 'method="get"' and after click on button url is not like `?page=1&`. Seems in my situation simlier solution would be to use `$_REQUEST`

Comment: @MarcelKorpel See http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the form like that, but when you submit it using `POST`, that specific variable will be stored completely in `$_POST['date_month']`.

In your case, when you submit the form, you will find only the `page` variable in `GET` (assuming there is no query string in `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]`).

So you just have to use:

```
$post_date_month = $_POST['date_month'];
```

However, if you want the user to only provide the month in one way (`post` or `get`), you'd better use something like (written out for clarity):

```
if (isset($_POST['date_month']))
{
  $post_date_month = $_POST['date_month'];
}
elseif (isset($_GET['date_month']))
{
  $post_date_month = $_GET['date_month'];
}
else
{
  // no month given, so for example:
  $post_date_month = '';
}
```

Comment: In the unlikely event of `<form method="POST" action="somepage.php?date_month=foo">`, *both* `$_POST['date_month']` and `$_GET['date_month']` will contain (different?) values.

Answer (score 1):

The code is a bit strange, but I think it's acceptable. Only be careful not to pass $_POST ang $_GET variables unescaped to the query, since it can be a vector for a Sql injection.